# How to count unique values with a dynamically range of date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Lets suppose a have this data frame:

```
Date       | ID
2014-01-01 | 134
2014-01-02 | 154
2014-01-03 | 123
...
2019-12-31 | 12433
```

For each row, i need to get the Date value and check in the same DataFrame x day ago until Date value and count unique ID values.
something like that:

```
Date       | ID  | UniqueIDs_x_days_ago
2014-01-01 | 134 |unique ID values between (2014-01-01 - x days) and 2014-01-01
2014-01-02 | 154 |unique ID values between (2014-01-02 - x days) and 2014-01-02
2014-01-03 | 123 |unique ID values between (2014-01-03 - x days) and 2014-01-03
...
2019-12-31 | 12433 |unique ID values between (2019-12-31 - x days) and 2019-12-31
```

Unfortunately i have a big data frame, so if possible i would like to know the fastes way to do it too.

Comment: How about starting us with a no-so-fastest method?

Comment: How have you tried to solve this so far?

Comment: @Allen give us a good way to solve it, but unfortunately my dataframe have like 6MM rows, so it take forever to do the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first calculate the start date, then slice the date range and count unique IDs.

```
x = 90

df['Date_Start'] = df.Date - pd.offsets.Day(x)
df=df.set_index('Date').sort_index()
df['UniqueIDs_x_days_ago'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[x.Date_Start: x.name].ID.nunique(), axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: That works,thank you! but i have another issue. My dataframe have like 6MM rows,runing like that will take forever(i already tried it). Do you have any ideia on how to run it on a dataframe with 6MM rows?